# Angular 4 Animation won't trigger on route change

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I've created the following animation in my Angular 4 project:

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

export function slide() {
    return trigger('slide', [
            transition('void => *', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
                animate('1s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1}))
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
                animate('1s 2s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1}))
            ])
        ])
  }
```

I've attached the animation to my component using the `host` property of the `@Component` decorator.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  animations: [slide()],
  host: {'[@slide]': '', 'style': 'display: block;'}
})
```

Now, I'd expect the animation to trigger at two points:
1. When the component is initialized, a.k.a when I hit the appropriate route
2. When I leave that route and navigate to another one

The first scenario works flawlessly, however the second one doesn't. What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get something similar to your animation working after some trial and error.

```
export function slideLeft() {
    return slide();
}

function slide() {
    return trigger('slide', [
        state('void', style({position:'absolute', width:'100%'}) ),
        state('*', style({position:'absolute', width:'100%'}) ),
        transition('void => *', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
            animate('1s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1 }),
            animate('1s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }))
        ])
    ]);
}
```

This is my animation code.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-away',
  templateUrl: './away.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./away.component.css'],
  animations: [ slideLeft() ],
  host: { '[@slide]': '' }
})
```

This is how I applied it to the component.

For the leaving animation, you have used the exact same properties for the entering animation. What you want is for the component you are animating to move from 0% to -100% on leaving.

I also added some **state** helper functions, which apply a style of **position: absolute** to take your component out of the normal flow of the page.

Hope this helps.