# Angular animations builder returned zero elements when the ":enter" is used in the query

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am using `AnimationBuilder` and `AnimationPlayer` to animate children elements using the `query` function

However it stops working when I use `:enter` in the query

```
private createAnimation(animation): AnimationFactory {
  return this.animationBuilder.build([
    query(
       // '.child-element',    // This works
      ':enter .child-element', // This does not work !
      [
        stagger(100, [useAnimation(animation)])
      ]
    )
  ]);
}
```

> ERROR
>   Error: Unable to create the animation due to the following errors: `query(":enter .child-element")` returned zero elements. (Use `query(":enter .child-element", { optional: true })` if you wish to allow this.)

I understand that the error was thrown because the elements were not rendered when the `createAnimation` function was called but then how can I apply the animation on children `:enter` event?

The same code above works if I use the traditional way of Angular animation, but I need this to be done dynamically at run time

Here is a [stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh4gnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

`query(:enter)` and `:leave` are broken use this link to know how to properly use transitions

[Angular 4 Animation won't trigger on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238275/angular-4-animation-wont-trigger-on-route-change)